# Консультация: давать или оказывать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Что-то меня вчера заклинило. Можно ли сказать "оказывать консультацию" или только "давать"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давать консультацию, совет, а оказывать помощь и т.п.  Возможно, но менее употребительно - предоставить консультацию.

Answer (score -1):

Только "дать" или "провести". Но никак не "оказать". Оказать можно помощь.